# display the items of arrayList into ListView, android

Tags: android, listview

I am writing android application, I get places and store them in ArrayList like this :

```
ArrayList<ExtendedOverlayItem> roadItems = new ArrayList<ExtendedOverlayItem>();
```

I pass this arrayList to a second activity like this:

```
 Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),List_hotels_ps.class);
       i.putExtra("hotels", roadItems);
       startActivity(i);
```

and in the second activity I want to display the content of the arrayList in a List view, I Google it, and it is like this:

```
 Intent i=getIntent();
         roadItems=(ArrayList<ExtendedOverlayItem>) i.getSerializableExtra("hotels");
         lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
          SimpleAdapter simpleAdpt = new SimpleAdapter(this, (List<? extends Map<String, ?>>) roadItems, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {"hotels"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
    lv.setAdapter(simpleAdpt);
```

but it is not working!!

I can't test it on the simulator :(

Comment: Just saying "not working" is a not enough. always put error logs, if possible

Answer (score 0):

ok, try this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
     new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, your_array_list);
     lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```